# Can I retrieve the index position of an element in a list?

Tags: c#

I have the following list:

```
private List<Car> _cars = new List<Car>();
```

I know I can check the size of the list with _cars.Count() but is it also possible for me to find out the sequence number of a Car item in the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Sequence Number" you are after is referred to as Index:

If you define a Car:

```
 Car myCar = new Car(){Make = "Ford", Model="Escort"};
 _cars.Add(myCar);
```

Then you obtain the Index as follows:

```
 int index = _cars.IndexOf(myCar);
```

If this is the only item in the list then index will be 0

Answer (score 2):

Check IndexOf Method : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[`List<T>.IndexOf(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx)

MSDN has a good example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`List.IndexOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx). Check out the [List Class reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) for more about what you can do with a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
Car car = new Car(...);
_cars.IndexOf(car);
```

Answer (score 1):

_cars.indexof(T)
Searches for the specified object and returns the zero-based index of the first occurrence within the entire List.